# FileNotFound Exception when accessing a network shared folder in java through windows service

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have one system (A) which is in domain and have another system (B) which is in workgroup.

I have shared a folder from system (B) with Everyone user (given Read/Write permission)

And, I'm trying to access that folder from System (A).

```
File file = new File("\\\\server\\sharedfolder");
System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
```

I am getting output as **true** when I run this code as java application.
But getting output as **false** when I run this code in Apache Tomcat Server which is running as windows service.

Comment: I am not sure if it is due to the fact that since your code is running on Apache, there are security constraints.

Comment: Have you tried using `java.nio.Path` instead of `java.io.File`? Are there different return values, too?

Comment: @deHaar I have tried using java.nio.Path, still it returns false.

Comment: OK, then it is obviously not a problem of your Java code. I think you have to check security constraints of your Tomcat as @npinti already stated.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to access the network shared path by running the Apache Tomcat as Specific user.

[image]

Thanks @npinti and @deHaar for your help.